# Help with Linear Congruence Problem

Tags: number-theory

I'm solving a larger (programming) problem in which I'm trying to work on my own solution which involves involves a smaller number theory problem and would like some help on the smaller problem by pointing out my mistakes or answering my questions. Thanks!

I have 3 variables a,b, and c.
I want to find all integers $x$ that satisfies the following conditions:

$Condition\ 1:\ $ $x = a - b * k$ where $x >= 0$ and $k >= 0$.

$Condition\ 2:\ $ $c$ is a divisor of $x$.

This was a online programming problem, and so I got a correct solution by just bruteforcing like this:

```
k = 0
while a - b * k >= 0:
    if d divides a-b*k 
        print k
    k = k + 1
```

But due to time limits, I need a faster solution.

**The following is what I've done so far but any suggestion on alternative approach is welcomed**

Combining the two conditions we have:

$(1.a)\  a - b*k \equiv 0 \;(\bmod\; c)$

which simplifies (if im not mistaken):

$(1.b)\  - b*k \equiv -a \;(\bmod\; c)$

So I have reduced the problem to finding the solution to the linear congruence $(1.b)$

However, since linear congruences can have infinitely many solutions and the algorithm for solving linear congruence seem to only solve a subset of those solutions (if I understand correctly), I'm confused on how to find the set of $x$'s that satisfy the two conditions. So my question is how to find the set of x's that satisfy the condition using the linear congruence if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas that might help you:

1) Since $x\geq 0$ this means that $0 \leq k \leq int(\frac{a}{b})$ so this bounds your $k$.
For clarity, by $int(z)$ I just mean the floor of $z$.

2) If hcf$(a,b,c) = 1$ then you have to solve $k \equiv ab^{-1}$ (mod $c$) where $k$ is your unknown. The notation $b^{-1}$ just stands for the smallest positive integer number less than $c$ such that $bb^{-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $c$). You can find it using the extended Euclidean Algorithm applied to $b$ and $c$.

3) Once you have $b^{-1}$ try to calculate $ab^{-1}$ and reduce it mod $c$. Let us call this value $u$.

4) Your solutions therefore are $k= lc +u$ where $l$ is such that $k$ is in the range described in 1). Having the values of $k$ you can calculate the values of $x$ simply by $x= a -bk$